# It's possible to pass login parameters through an asp.net site like this?

Tags: asp.net

i'm making a **scraper** system... it's a challange by my teacher.

The idea is make a mobile app to do and store a class register, this way make possible to the teacher do your job into your smartphone and upload this data later.

We dont have access to college system, but we are imagining this scenario:

The App receive the data like Username and Password through your own graphic interface and make a login request to College WebSite simulating a human user.

The problem is know how to pass the login data by POST into the system... because the URL doesn't show the parameter entries like:

```
http://website.com/login.php?name=user
```

I'm looking for some idea... that help me to see the login parameters used in the browser request on the login process, after that i wanna try to loggin into the system by using URL parameters if possible or some other way.

the website is:

https://www.sigacentropaulasouza.com.br/fatec/login.aspx

---

UPDATED!!!

---

i'd a firebug installation into my browser and i saw something interesting in the Network Console of this plugin:

In the header, i saw something like:

Refer = https://www.sigacentropaulasouza.com.br/fatec/login.aspx?MyUserName,MyPassWord

so... i've trying to access my profile page by passing this URL into my browser.

Without Success!

I think... because this page uses the HTTPS probably?!

Any idea?

Comment: Usually if I need to see what data is being sent to and from a browser I use something called 'FIDDLER2' (although this kind of advice should be in the software recommendations site).

Comment: Fiddler isn't necessary, though it's handy. Just about any browser you can view the developers tools (press F12 on keyboard) and view the network traffic.